# getAdapter() is null after setAdapter()

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

In `onCreateView` method of a fragment I prepare the adapter for a recycler view:

```
ProfileAdapter profileAdapter;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_list_fragment, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, root);

    setRetainInstance(true);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        profileAdapter = new ProfileAdapter(getContext(), this);
        profileAdapter.items.add(...)
    }

    recyclerView.setAdapter(profileAdapter);
    recyclerView.requestFocus();
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecycleViewItemDecorator(getContext()));
    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

    return root;
}
```

The works fine. I tested it on many devices. However I just got a crash report form a customer. The app crashed at this line with a **java.lang.NullPointerException**:

```
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But I cannot reproduce this error. Why should the adapter be null right after it was set?

The customers phone is a HTC One S with android 4.1. My app is build with android 6 and min supported version is 4.1.

Do you see any reason why the adapter is null? From my point of view the only reason is that the adapter was not retained, e.g. on orientation change. But why should this work on my Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android 4.1) and not on a HTC One S?

Comment: Yeah it looks like `savedInstanceState` is not null, therefore not setting a value for profileAdapter.

Comment: You're creating the profileAdapter in a conditional - apparently you have a situation where savedInstanceState is not null, and profileAdapter is null

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek without the if condition the adapter would be recreated on rotation. setRetainInstance(true) retains the adapter.  However for the customer for some reason it was not retained...

Comment: Try checking to see if the adapter is null instead

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 
 `recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();` in `onActivityCreated` method rather than `onCreateView`.

It may return `null` because `root` view is not yet attached to the fragment or activity.

Answer (score 0):

If Fragment will restore from backstack, for example if user pressed home button and Activity task will destroy, savedState will not be null, but adapter will.